# How to keep variable constant even after page refresh in PHP

Tags: php, function, variables, get, text-files

I'm making a simple hangman application and I have my php file and a separate .txt file holding the words, one on each line.

What I want is for the $word variable to remain constant even after the page refreshes since I was planning on using a GET or POST to get the user's input.

In the example code below I want $word to stay the same after the form is submitted.
I believe it's a simple matter of moving code to another place but I can't figure out where any help for this PHP noob would be appreciated!

**wordsEn1.txt:**

```
cat
dog
```

**functions.php:**

```
<?php

function choose_word($words) {
    return trim($words[array_rand($words)]);
}
?>
```

**hangman.php:**

```
<?php
include('functions.php');

$handle = fopen('wordsEn1.txt', 'r');
$words = array();

while(!feof($handle)) {
$words[] = trim(fgets($handle));
}

$word = choose_word($words);

echo($word);
echo('<form><input type="text" name="guess"></form>');
?>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use sessions:

```
session_start();   // in top of PHP file
...
$_SESSION["word"] = choose_word($words);
```

`$_SESSION["word"]` will be there on refresh

if you care about the "lifetime", follow also this (put it just before `session_start`)

```
session_set_cookie_params(3600,"/");
```

It will hold an **hour** for the entire domain **("/")**

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hidden input:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="hidden" name="word" value="<?php echo $word; ?>" />
</form>
```

...and on the next page:

```
if(isset($_POST['word'])) {
    echo $_POST['word'];
}
```

---

Or you could use a PHP [$_COOKIE](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp), which can be called forever (but kind of a waste if you just want it on the next page):

```
setcookie('word', $word, time()+3600, '/');
```

...and on the next page:

```
echo $_COOKIE['word'];
```

Comment: This will not work if the user presses F5 to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Just use hidden type forms for that issue.if we put it into session while page refreshes its hide also. if you can store that value in hidden form field it was stored and retrived any time .